# Bug in for loop with short primitive in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, short

I've found a very odd thing in Java which seems to be a bug. A for loop doesn't to correctly evaluate the condition for a short value at 32767 (the maximum value, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)). See the example code below. Am I missing something here?

```
for (short i = 32766; i <= 32767; i++) {
    System.out.println("i is now " + i);
    if (i < 0) {
        System.out.println("This should never be printed");
        break;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
i is now 32766
i is now 32767
```

Actual output:

```
i is now 32766
i is now 32767
i is now -32768
This should never be printed
```

Comment: Hint for the future: if you think that a compiler, runtime or commonly-used library has a major bug, you're *usually* wrong (not always, but it's the safer assumption).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Every** possible `short` value is `<= 32767`, because 32767 is [the biggest number that a `short` can hold](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#MAX_VALUE).

That means that the condition of your `if` will always be true and your loop will never end.

The value wraps around to `Short.MIN_VALUE` due to overflow (which does not throw an exception in Java).

General note: there are *very few* legitimate reasons to use a `short` in Java, almost all calculation, loop counting and so on should be done with `int` (or `long` as appropriate). `short` isn't generally any faster and it won't generally save you any space (except if you have an array).

Comment: Yes, stupid of me.. I've fixed it now using: for (short i = 32766; i > 0; i++). Thanks

Comment: Just an example, with byte instead short: 01111111 is 127. next number should be 10000000, but the first digit means "negative", so your are obtaining -128 (the lowest available value working with bytes)

Answer (score 3):

When you enter the `for` loop with `Short.MAX_VALUE` (which is 2^15 - 1, that is 32767) the condition `i <= 32767` still holds!

As a result, `i` is incremented and you go into the loop once again... With i now being `Short.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the condition is `<=32767` the condition is TRUE and the value of `i` is incremented once again. Since the max value of `short` is 32767, incrementing it by one makes `i` equal to -32768 which is still smaller or equal than 32767.

> short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

Take a look here: [Primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)